# How should I take duration into account for trade routes?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-gathering-storm

The title says it. When creating a trade route, there's a "duration" (I think) next to a clock to the right of the name of the city. How does this affect game play?

I looked at https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Trade_Route_(Civ6) but did not really understand it.

Answer (score 5):

Duration affects how long until you can change your trade route. This can matter when political alliances shift.

As the trade value is expressed on a per turn basis, trade route duration has no further impact that I am aware of.

**Update** Eric makes a valid point about trading posts being created only when a route completes.

Comment: Don't forget that the trading post is only established once the trade route completes. Trading posts allow your routes to "refresh" their movement (reach) in cities they pass through, enabling them to reach previously unreachable empires. This is quite important for cultural victories and the duration of routes may impact the need to settle closer if possible.

Comment: @Eric Good point, amended answer.